# Antlr v4 Can I ignore mismatched input?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I'm attempting to make a parser to recognise units of measure and then using a listener convert units as needed.  However when parsing a test sentence I get a missed matched input error when the parser sees the units in other parts of the text such as in the middle of words.  Here is a cut down version of my code.

UnitsOfMeasure.g4

```
grammar UnitsOfMeasure;

import
    ImperialUnitsParser;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * UNITS OF MEASURE PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
include_metric_units
    : imperial_types
    | include_metric_units imperial_types
    ;

imperial_types
    : i_area
    ;

i_area
    : QUANTITY square_inch
    | QUANTITY square_feet
    | QUANTITY square_mile
    | QUANTITY square_yard
    ;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * UNITS OF MEASURE - LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SQUARE
    : [S|s]'quare'
    | [S|s]'q' '.'?
    ;

SQUARED
    : [S|s]'quared'
    | '^2'
    | '<sup>2</sup>'
    | '&#178'
    | '\u00B2'
    ;

fragment PLURAL
    : 's'  ?
    | 'es' ?
    ;

QUANTITY
    : '-'? FLOAT
    | '-'? DIGITS
    ;

FLOAT
    : DIGITS '.' DIGITS
    ;

fragment DIGITS
    : DIGIT+
    ;

fragment DIGIT
    : '0'..'9'
    ;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * SKIP EVERYTHING ELSE
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
 EVERYTHING 
    : . -> skip 
    ;
```

ImperialUnitsParser.g4

```
parser grammar ImperialUnitsParser;

import ImperialUnitsLexer;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * AREA
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
square_inch
    : SQUARE INCH
    | INCH SQUARED
    ;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LENGTH
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
inch
    : INCH
    ;
```

ImperialUnitsLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar ImperialUnitsLexer;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * BASE UNITS
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
INCH
    : [I|i]'nch' PLURAL
    | [I|i]'n' '.'?
    ;
```

Convert.java

```
public static String includeMetricUnits(String parse) throws UnitsOfMeasureParserRuntimeException
{           
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(parse);

    ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(builder.toString());
    UnitsOfMeasureLexer lexer = new UnitsOfMeasureLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    UnitsOfMeasureParser parser = new UnitsOfMeasureParser(tokens);
    parser.addParseListener(new UnitsOfMeasureParseListener(builder));
    parser.addErrorListener(new UnitsOfMeasureErrorListener());
    parser.include_metric_units(0);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

So the listener here does some editing of the builder as the stream is parsed.  A working example of this is the following:

*"A whiteboard with 1550 square inches of writing space"* returns:

*"A whiteboard with 1550in<sup>2</sup>(1m<sup>2</sup>) of writing space"*

However when I make this a bit more complex by adding in more than one unit it reports the following:

> line 1:44 mismatched input 'in' expecting {EOF, QUANTITY}

on:

*"A whiteboard with 1550 square inches of writing space, and a touchscreen measuring 775 square inches"* returns:

*"A whiteboard with 1550in<sup>2</sup>(1m<sup>2</sup>) of writing space, and a touchscreen measuring 775 square inches"*

Following the debugger it performs the first conversion without error and then drops out after it's look ahead.  I probably haven't got the recursive part quite right but essentially the grammar is supposed to keep looking until it finds a quantity followed by a unit of measure.  If the quantity is not followed by a recognised unit it should just ignore it and continue.

From the error I can see that it picked up the 'in' in 'writing' as I have a Lexer rule to recognise this as inches but because there is no quantity it throws an error.

Can anyone help me with this issue so that I can get the grammar to ignore inputs that don't match?  And can anyone tell me if i'm getting the recursive bit right so that it continues till the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't want to match the token `INCH` when it's part of another word, you'll need to match words, and skip these:

```
WORD
 : [a-zA-Z]+ -> skip
 ;
```

Just be sure you place this rule *after* your `INCH` rule, otherwise it'd match the input `"in"` as a word too (which you obviously don't want). You'll also want to expand the character this rule matches: only ascii letter won't suffice.

Also, `[I|i]` matches the pipe char as well: do `[Ii]` instead.

Although correct:

```
include_metric_units
    : imperial_types
    | include_metric_units imperial_types
    ;
```

it's rather *LR/Bison*-esque. More readable would be to write:

```
include_metric_units
    : imperial_types+
    ;
```

And to match tokens that might be in the token stream, but are not matches by any of your productions, simply match any token in your top level rule:

```
parse
  :  ( include_metric_units // match metrics
     | .                    // or any "dangling" single token
     )*                     // zero or more times
     EOF                    // end of the input
  ;

include_metric_units
  :  imperial_types+
  ;
```

Yes, that is correct: the `.` (DOT) inside a production/parser rule matches a single token, not a single character. It only matches a single character in lexer rules.

When I now parse the input

```
A whiteboard with 1550 square inches of writing space, and 
a touchscreen measuring 775 square inches and an in at the end...
```

(note the `'in'` at the end!), I get the following parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for such a great answer :)  Just a quick question, i'm currently working on gallons where the format might be x gallons (UK).  Will having the PLURAL rule stop a space from being added between gallons and (UK) because my rule [Gg]'allon' PLURAL? UK_IMP isn't being picked up and my best guess is that PLURAL in my test case is matching the empty character and even though I'm skipping spaces it doesn't seem to pick it up at all.

Comment: Seems I managed to get round it by using [Gg]'allon' PLURAL? WS*? UK_IMP, although I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: @AlexeiBlue, yes adding `WS*?` (or just `WS*`) to it should do the trick. The spaces are only skipped inside parser rules. They are not skipped as part of lexer rules, as you found out.

Answer (score 1):

Using a parser for a freeform language is not a good idea. What you'd rather need is a kinda keyword spotting. You look through your input, e.g. using regular expressions, for some forms of recognizable input and extract the exact values from this string subpart.

A parser needs a well defined language, that is, a language that you can put in rules in its entirety (unambiguiously). With free input text just a little different grammar, a fill word, a typo etc. will completely break your parsing.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your answer, my only worry with this approach is that I will need to preform a regex search for each kind of unit which could get very slow.  I've added an unwanted rule which catches matching individual Lexer so it can be ignored.  Currently this is working for the example above and for unit tests I've written for volume.  I'm going to continuing writing more unit tests and see if I can break it and also look at writing some performance comparisons, I'll update this with an answer once i've got more functionality and testing finished.  Will be interesting to see the results

Comment: Interesting topic, indeed. From what I see, however, it's not clear if you just want to parse the units + values (what I essentially suggested) out of any kind of text (including HTML it seems). Your test cases seem to indicate free text. How do you extract the text you parse at the end?

Comment: So the text that is parsed is also copied to a StringBuilder at the start and added to the listener.  As the text is parsed, calls to listener are made which set up the units to convert from.  The listener then manipulates the builder after exiting a second to top level parser rule such as 'i_area' shown above.  The name of that rule will likely change to 'include_metric_after_imperial_area' which looks for a unit of imperial area and then adds the metric equivalent after in brackets.  The listener also converts the units to a standard form and removes spacing.

Comment: In time I want to be able to add more top level rules like include_metric_units_first which will handle the builder differently to do the same but put the imperial units in brackets afterwards.  Once I have all top level rules the idea is to add hooks to this parser from a top level parser with strict language grammar so that I can say 'include metric units in <attr>', where attr is a semantic predicate which must match a attribute name for a data type such as 'Description'.  From there the top level rule can pass the Description to the UnitsOfMeasure parser which iterates over the text once.

Comment: *"Using a parser for a freeform language is not a good idea"* you're absolutely right about that, but that is not what @AlexeiBlue is doing. He is "cherry picking" certain tokens from the input, and discarding most of the ones that do not resemble the desired input. In no way is he trying to define an English grammar.